# how to extract session user_data stored in database in ci_session table?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am storing my session data in CI_SESSION table. How should extract it from the table? I am trying to get user_data field.

Should i use model and query the table, or i can access it as normal session variable? I couldn't find answer on that question in Codeigniter manual.

Regards, John

Comment: Are you inserting the session data in to the database with your own code? Or letting CI do it for you (`$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE`)? If CI is handling it, you only need to retrieve the data using the session class as you normally would (eg. `$this->session->userdata('some_session_item')`

Comment: CI is handling it. but even that user_data field has value, i am getting empty field back. Data is stored in fairly stange format, ie:a:2:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:10:"formValues";b:0;}

Comment: When I unserialize that data, both user_data and formValues are empty. Make sure you are setting them correctly with `$this->session->set_userdata()`.

Comment: Any chance that you have some time to help me with this on chat? I am struggling with this 2 days now, and i can't solve it.

Comment: I am storing the value like this:  $this->session->set_userdata('formValues', $formValues);
            
            $mySessData = $this->session->userdata('formValues');

Comment: I cannot use chat right now, sorry. Have you verified that $formValues is not empty?

Comment: i just checked it again, it is not empty. on the first page of the results, it shows the value. on the next page, (using pagination) values are gone, since there the form is not submitted.

Comment: when i unserialize the data, i get the following: Array ( [user_data] => [formValues] => ) My var is: 1  However, i think that i need catid = 1, not just 1

Comment: or the 1 means that array is empty?

Comment: it is empty sorry...i guess i am to tired...

Comment: show all your code and you will get more help